# Deep Learning Model to predict polygon centroids

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, coordinate-systems

I know this seems like complicating a very simple problem, but I have been instructed to do this by my supervisor who wishes to find the centroid of each molecular face of a large molecule. This problem can be reduced to finding the centroid of an n-sided polygon, where `n>=3` and can vary between polygons. The input to the model is a set of vertices of the polygon, where each vertex is represented as 3D coordinates, and the output must be the 3D coordinates of the centroid.

I have tried executing a Graph Convolutional Network with the ReLU function for this approach, with input dimension as 3 (for the 3D coordinates) and output dimension as 3, thinking that I would obtain the x, y and z coordinates the 3 output dimensions. However, what I get is a prediction of the centroid based on each vertex of the polygon, and not based on the polygon itself.

To tackle this problem, I have formulated the problem of finding the centroid vector z as finding weights `w1, w2, w3....wn` such that `z=w1 * z1 + w2 * z2 + w3 * z3 + ... + wn * zn`, where the ideal values of `w1, w2, w3,.....,wn` would be `1/n`. Using the GCN with the softmax function, even though I achieved satisfactory predictions for the weights, the results for the centroid was far from satisfactory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach of using the softmax function should work, since the sum of all weights `wi` should be 1. In fact, if you train the network for a fairly small number of epochs, the values of `w1` will converge to your required values.

One possible architecture which I can think of is below:

```
    def __init__(self, input, hidden, output):
        # Add code here:
        
        # GCN architecture. You can use the GCNConv instead of CustomGraphConv
        self.gcn1=CustomGraphConv(input, hidden)
        self.gcn2=CustomGraphConv(hidden, hidden)
        self.fc=nn.Linear(hidden, output)
        self.softmax=nn.Softmax(dim=0)
        
    def forward(self, x, edges):
        x=self.gcn1(x, edges)
        x=F.relu(x)
        x=self.gcn2(x, edges)
        x=F.relu(x)
        x=self.fc(x)
        x=self.softmax(x)
        return x
```

Take care of the dimensions of the tensor before proceeding with this code, especially for the Softmax function.